# global variable is not working in php5.6

Tags: php-5.6

I am using PHP 5.6. When I try to print using $GLOBALS["var"] inside the function scope, is displaying nothing on browser window.
Here is my code---

```
 <?php
    $var=100;
    function showGlobalVariable()
    {
         printf($GLOBALS["var"]);
     }
 ?>
```

Comment: Where are you calling the function?

Comment: can we display the output directly from function rather than calling it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the function:

```
<?php

$var = 100;

function showGlobalVariable(){
    printf("The value is %d",$GLOBALS['var']);
}

showGlobalVariable();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `printf` function needs a format string as first argument. Try

```
printf("%d", $GLOBALS["var"]);
```